# what are intermediate systems in ssl

Tags: wcf, ssl

While reading about Transfer security, I read that "Transport security is good when you don't have intermediate system between your client and service".

What do we mean by "Intermediate systems" ?? .

Comment: Do you understand 'intermediate'? Do you understand 'system'?

Comment: Actually transport security is great no matter whether you have any intermediate system between your client and service or not.

Comment: I just found a partial answer in this document from MS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647097.aspx

Part of it says:

Message layer security that uses X.509 certificates is flexible enough to provide point-to-point or end-to-end security. This allows messages to be persisted in a secure state for short periods for queue-based processing or for longer periods in an archived state.

So an example would be if a message were queued or stored off to disk. It would stay encrypted through the time it was processed and deleted from disk, presumably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SSL, the security properties only hold between the two endpoints of the connexion. If you have intermediate systems then the SSL security will be provided between your system and the intermediate system. Not between your system and the final system.

Here intermetiate systems are WCF servers.

Comment: HI , Not getting intermediate systems.. does it mean the routers etc that come inbetweeen the communication ??

Comment: @manojaggarwal No. They are WCF systems.